# How to check AutoStart option is already on for my App in Xiaomi phone Security App programmatically in android

Tags: android, permissions, autostart

I can open AutoStart intent for my app with following code......

```
   try {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        String manufacturer = android.os.Build.MANUFACTURER;
        if ("xiaomi".equalsIgnoreCase(manufacturer)) {
            intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.miui.securitycenter", "com.miui.permcenter.autostart.AutoStartManagementActivity"));
        } else if ("oppo".equalsIgnoreCase(manufacturer)) {
            intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.coloros.safecenter", "com.coloros.safecenter.permission.startup.StartupAppListActivity"));
            //intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.coloros.oppoguardelf", "com.coloros.powermanager.fuelgaue.PowerConsumptionActivity"));
        } else if ("vivo".equalsIgnoreCase(manufacturer)) {
            intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.vivo.permissionmanager", "com.vivo.permissionmanager.activity.BgStartUpManagerActivity"));
        } else if ("huawei".equalsIgnoreCase(manufacturer)) {
            intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.huawei.systemmanager", "com.huawei.systemmanager.optimize.process.ProtectActivity"));
        }

        List<ResolveInfo> list = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
        if (list.size() > 0) {
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

But this will always open permission intent though AutoStart permission is on. How can I check this AutoStart permission is on or off before starting the intent?

Comment: The MIUI doesn't provider a getter function on Autostart function so it's not possible for now!

Comment: @HoseinIT is it possible now?

Comment: @Royz I don't know I am not in Android Development anymore